# how to append a textbox to a checkbox list item which is coming from a sharepoint list on select of a list item

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a custom input form some of the fields are coming from a list in SharePoint 2010. I have a check box control which is populated by a list item. there are around 10 rows.

Now I want when a user select a check box list item, a text box should appear beside it. for example I have a list called subjects, which have column name title and the entries are physics, maths, chem etc... Now when a user select physics from the check box list a text-box should appear beside it and user should be able to write on text box.

```
protected void chkbox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (ListItem checkbox in chkbox1.Items)
   {
      //If this particular item is checked
      if (checkbox.selected)
      {
         checkbox.Text = String.Format("{0}<input id=\"TextBox{0}\" name=\"TextBox{0}\" / >", checkbox.Value);
         //TextBox tb = new TextBox { ID = checkbox.Value };
         //Input.Controls.Add(tb);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your needs seems a lot more simple to do with JavaScript. I won't use C# for that. :)

Comment: Please provide some example code that SP is displaying.

Comment: @Thibault Gandon could u help me with the way.

Answer (score 0):

I took some guesses based on your description. Here is a way you can do this via JQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pw0vrvfh/

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk-01" />
      <label for="chk-01">Physics</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk-02" />
      <label for="chk-02">Math</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk-03" />
      <label for="chk-03">Chemistry</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk-04" />
      <label for="chk-04">Label 4</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk-05" />
      <label for="chk-05">Label 5</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk-06" />
      <label for="chk-06">Label 6</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk-07" />
      <label for="chk-07">Label 7</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk-08" />
      <label for="chk-08">Label 8</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk-09" />
      <label for="chk-09">Label 9</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk-10" />
      <label for="chk-10">Label 10</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[id^='chk-']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      var chkId = $(this).attr("id");
      var inpId = chkId.substring(chkId.indexOf("-") + 1);
      var $inp = $("<input />", {
        type: "text",
        name: "TextBox" + inpId,
        id: "TextBox" + inpId
      });
      $(this).next("label").after($inp);
    } else {
      var chkId = $(this).attr("id");
      var inpId = chkId.substring(chkId.indexOf("-") + 1)
      $("#TextBox"+inpId).remove();
    }
  });
});
```

A new `input` is created, using the ID of the current `checkbox` for consistency. You could easily change the ID to `value` or even an array: `TextBox[]` if you like.

I bound to the `.change()` event so that I could check the state of the `checkbox` each time. This allows for the user to change their mind. You could also collect the text from the `input` before removing it. Put that into `.data()` in case the user unchecks the wrong one. If there is data for that checkbox, you could replace it the next time it's checked. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pw0vrvfh/2/

Comment: the thing is the checkbox list item is coming from SharePoint List

Comment: Ok, provide some example context.

Comment: I have a list in sharepoint called Subjects which have some items called physics, maths, etc.  i have created a visual web part. chkbox1 is the name of the control in the visual part, its bound to the Subjects list in SP.
Now i want when a user select listbox item 1 a text box should appear beside it. the list is a multiselect checkbox list.

Comment: The problem is how do I get the checkbox list item selected id? and how do i bind it to textbox. the user should be able to enter the custom data in the textbox and the data gets stored.